# is it possible to change css properties of class label in nativescript

Tags: css, nativescript

I have used label class for every label in my project. If any other font color like

> class="label font-clr-green"

is applied then it not taking green color. So I decided to overwrite the label class in app.css but it's also a failure. I need to know whether label class can be overridden or not.

Comment: Which ever CSS class was declared at last in your app.css may take higher precedence, so if you want to overwrite same attributes from previous class make sure you declare that at last. If you still have issues, please share a Playground sample.

Comment: Have u tried adding '!important' to the overwritten properties.

e.g: 'color': 'green !important'

Comment: no i need to try... ill share a playground sample

Comment: https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=jmiQIh

Comment: the problem part is mentioned in xml by comments

Answer (score 0):

I checked your Playground Sample and what I could deduce from it is, that the `<Label>` used in the problem part is not taking the green color as it should be. Well, that's because you are using this `<Label>` element inside a `<StackLayout>` having class `input-field`. It seems like, CSS for `.input-field Label` is pre-defined.

The solution to your problem, would be to rename this class `input-field` to something else. That's all it needed. Below is the updated XML part. You can also check my  attached Playground demo with the fix.

```
<Page loaded="pageLoaded" class="page" xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd">

<ActionBar title="Home" class="action-bar">
</ActionBar>
<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout class="form">
        <!--this was working fine -->
        <Label textWrap="true" text="Play with NativeScript!" class="label font-weight-bold m-b-5 fcg" /> 
        <Label textWrap="true" text="Play with NativeScript!" class="label font-weight-bold m-b-5"
            color="green" />


        <!-- the problem was here, solution was to rename input-field to input-field-1  -->
        <StackLayout class="input-field-1">
            <StackLayout class="okay">
            <Label text="Active Flag" class="label font-weight-bold m-b-5 fcg" />
            </StackLayout>
            <Switch checked="true" class="switch fcg"
                horizontalAlignment='left' margin="0" />
            <StackLayout class="hr-light"></StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>

    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Working [Playground Demo](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=jmiQIh&v=4).